# Ajax and scope problems

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having some problems with AJAX and the scope of my data. I am new to Javascript and I'm not sure how to fix my problem.

```
  var urlList = new Array();
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:3000/url",
      success: function(data) {
         alert(data.expressions.url); //This shows the correct result
         urlList[0] = obj.expressions.dom;
      }
  });

  alert(urlList[0]); //this shows undefined
```

I need the data that is in `urlList[0]` so i can use it at a later time. I think it's a scope problem.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Where does `obj.expressions.dom` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a scope problem, but a timing problem. The ajax method is executed asynchronously. That means that calling it will not cause your program to wait until it is finished. This results in the alert being shown before the request is finished.

To fix this, put the request inside the success function as well. This is the proper place to handle the results of the request.

```
var urlList = new Array();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/url",
    success: function(data) {

        alert(data.expressions.url); //This shows the correct result

        urlList[0] = obj.expressions.dom;

        // This might work now, depending on what `obj.expressions.dom` is. This
        // isn't becoming clear from your code. Usually you would use the `data`
        // parameter of the success function, which contains the response body of
        // the ajax request that has just finished.
        alert(urlList[0]);

        // of course you can call other functions as well. For instance, you 
        // could call
        urlListChanged();
        // ..which you can declare in global scope. This way, you can repond to 
        // changes  from multiple sources, without having to duplicate code.
        // It will all work, as long as you use the success handler as the trigger.
    }
});


function urlListChanged()
{
   alert(urlList[0]);
}
```

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: @cjsmith Good point, but beyond the scope of the question and its answer, I think. I didn't want to overhaul OP's approach, just wanted to focus on the problem. The problem and its solution would be the same when using `.done()`. Thanks for the addition, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of chronology.

`$.ajax` fires an asynchronous request, meaning the rest of your code after it will continue to be executed before the request has resolved. Since `urlList` is populated only once the request resolves, your alert is firing too early.

Change

```
$.ajax...
```

to

```
var req = $.ajax...
```

and wrap your alert in a success callback:

```
req.done(function() { alert(urlList[0]); });
```

...or just move the alert inside your existing `success` callback.